# Is there a corresponding optic for higher-order traversable functors?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, category-theory, traversable, haskell-hedgehog

[Hedgehog](https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog) has an `HTraversable` class defined like this:

```
-- | Higher-order traversable functors.
--
class HTraversable t where
  htraverse :: Applicative f => (forall a. g a -> f (h a)) -> t g -> f (t h)
```

Which is used with their [`Var`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.2/hedgehog-0.5/Hedgehog.html#t:Var) type for parameterizing a type over whether values are concrete or abstract. `t` has kind `(* -> *) -> *` and is a higher order functor although they don't actually have that class, `f`, `g` and `h` have kind `* -> *`. I've seen the same thing defined in a few different libraries.

Is there a way to get an optic out of this? I confess I don't know what that would even do, and I'm not super comfortable with lenses or regular `Traversable` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
type HTraversal s t a b =
    forall f. Applicative f => (forall x. a x -> f (b x)) -> s -> f t

htraverse :: HTraversable t => HTraversal (t a) (t b) a b
```

Remember, `lens`'s `Traversal` comes about by taking the type of `traverse` and letting the `t a` and `t b` types vary, viewing the traversable not as a polymorphic container but as a monolithic blob.

How useful `HTraversal` is, I dunno. You can't compose them nicely with `(.)`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So there's a corresponding thing, but it doesn't really fit with the other optics. I wonder if there are a set of "higher order optics" that this does work with.

Comment: `HTraversable` is for objects in the category of functors from the functor category to Hask. You can work with the category of _endofunctors_ on the functor category (such as monad transformers), for which `Traversable` would look like `itraverse :: Applicative f => (forall x. a x -> f (b x)) -> (forall x. s x -> f (t x))`. Traversals of this type do compose with `(.)`, and you can build out prisms etc too. Neither `HTraversable` nor `ITraversable` would interoperate with `lens`, though, because they're built on a different category.